# Remove auto added <p> from a page that has no literal content (uses shortcodes)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress powered website that on the homepage uses a static page with nothing but shortcodes to generate the content.

The page gets these shortcodes by setting the front page to a static page and using the_content(); on page.php. The page content has no spaces, only shortcodes, so looks something like this:

```
[content-shortcode blah blah][more content-shortcode blah blah]
```

It all works fine, except that WordPress adds an empty `<p></p>` before the shortcodes code and another P /P at the end of all the shortcodes code (Nothing in between shortcodes).

How can I remove them? I do not want to disable the global wpautop removal function though, as it can be useful for some users, I only want to remove the first and last P's that appear on the homepage.

Comment: there are so many solutions to the problem..just google: `wordpress shortcodes p`. One possible solution: [http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/2011/02/wordpress-wrapping-shortcodes-with-p-tags/](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/2011/02/wordpress-wrapping-shortcodes-with-p-tags/)

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried googling but wasn't able to find anything like that, thank you! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few things you can try.

You can pospone the `wp_autop` because it processes before the shortcode output:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Or use the [`cleanup_shortcode_fix()`](http://pastebin.com/USBetJAj) function that should help with your issue:

```
function cleanup_shortcode_fix($content) {
    $array = array('<p>[' => '[', ']</p>' => ']', ']<br />' => ']', ']<br>' => ']');
    $content = strtr($content, $array);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix');
$string = preg_replace_('/<p>s*</p>/', '', $string);
add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix', 1);
```

Comment: Brilliant bit of code! I struggled for two days, and hundreds of code lines with this issue. This resolved all the wordpress editor paragraph/br tag madness in 8 tidy lines.

Answer (score 2):

There are various functions aside from `wpautop()` that [filter post content](http://codex.wordpress.org/How_WordPress_Processes_Post_Content), such as `force_balance_tags()`, which was designed to balance bad HTML coming in via the editor.

They're mostly defined in [formatting.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php), where you can see the various code in source.

Removal of these filters can be as simple as one line, as you point out:

`remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

For more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Check out below links which will help you.

1. [Removing <p> and <br/> tags in WordPress posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts/6627460#6627460)
2. [wordpress-wrapping-shortcodes-with-p-tags](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/formatting.php)
3. [Disable wpautop Plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/disable-wpautop/)

may this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this(paste this code somewhere in `functions.php`):

```
function shortcode_empty_paragraph_fix($content){   
    $array = array (
        '<p>[' => '[', 
        ']</p>' => ']', 
        ']<br />' => ']'
    );

    $content = strtr($content, $array);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'shortcode_empty_paragraph_fix');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to only remove `<p>` tags on the home page, add the code below to your `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'remove_autop_from_home');
function remove_autop_from_home() {
    // check to see if we are on the home page
    if(is_home()) {
        remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('p:empty').remove();
```

Also you can use JS. Above code will help you to remove all empty p tag from the page

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks so much Munni!