# Wordpress inserting opening <p> tag inside of my shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written a small function to display the latest video on my startpage. The function itself works just fine. The only problem is, that wordpress keeps inserting an opening `<p>` tag at one place of the code.
Here is my function:

```
function video_start() {
// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'page','post_parent'=>'17','order'=>'ASC','orderby' => 'date','posts_per_page'=>1));
// The Loop 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
{
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) 
    {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
        {
            $picid = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
            $alt_text = get_post_meta($picid , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
            $string .= '<div class="featured-start">';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" class="b-link" rel="bookmark">';
            $string .= '<h2 class="mar-bot">Latest Video</h2>';
            $string .= '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)).'" class="img-responsive" alt="'.$alt_text.'" />';
            $string .= '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>';
            $string .= '<div class="orange-button">Watch Video</div></a></div>';
        }
    }
}
else 
{
// no posts found
}
$string .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
return $string;
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('video_startpage', 'video_start');
// Enable shortcodes in text widgets
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

The output I am having a problem with is this:

```
<div class="featured-start">
<a href="http://www.kundenwebseite.inweco.de/videos/pet-project-09-part-1/" class="b-link" rel="bookmark"><br />
<h2 class="mar-bot">Latest Video</h2>
<p><img src="http://www.kundenwebseite.inweco.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/pet-project-2009-part-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
<p>Pet Project 09 &#8211; Part 1</p>
<div class="orange-button">Watch Video</div>
<p></a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I have tried removing the wp-autop filter several ways but it simply wont work. And even after using google for over two hours now i cant find a solution.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15435478/1456997

Comment: I did. It gives me the following error:

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'p' in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. After a long search ( with a lot of help from Steve ) i have finally found a solution.
I took the wpautop function ( beginning in line 456 and ending in line 604 ) from

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0

and replaced the existing wpautop function in the formatting.php file found in the /wp-includes/ folder with the new qpautop function from the provided link.
Then i commented the line 499 out.

All of that got it to work for me.

Comment: I totally forgot that. But its done now. Thank you again for all your help!

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue since years. Please have a look at [Wordpress Ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/6984).

As others maybe mentioned before, there is a Plugin to fix this issue. It is called "[Shortcode Empty Paragraph Fix](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/reviews/?filter=1)". Its not the best solution but not so bad.

Im not a fan of putting a lot of bloat to my wp installation - so i wrapped the shortcode in a div without a class and fixed the problem.

```
<div> [woocommerce_cart] </div>
```

I hope the issue will adressed in the next few years ;) so i can remove my divs - in my opinion a saver way, because sometimes extra functions in the funcitons.php can cause some problems down the road.

Comment: Cool workaround! Still experience the issue in wp5 even though in the widget where I use it the shortcode is in a special shortcode block. So replaced with custom html block and inserted your code and works.

Answer (score 0):

The wpautop() function is in wp-includes/formatting.php which allows you to specify whether you want a `<p>` or not but it seems that passing the arguments to switch it off is not working in your case - these methods might be of some use.

This one uses `str_replace()` which is not so bad, and offers several other options:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-is-being-surrounded-by-p-tags

also an offering on that same page which removes the newlines which are being converted automatically into `<p>` tags  `str_replace(array("\n\r", "\n", "\r"), '', $content );`

This is a plugin offered on that page but I don't know if it is OK - you seem to be able to take the function offered and add it to your `functions.php` - if you have a child theme https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes you can put it in the functions.php inside that so it doesn't get lost when your parent theme is updated. (Regarded as best practice).

https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried that as well with no success.

Comment: This didn't work?  remove_filter( 'do_shortcode', 'wpautop' ); like 
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );

Comment: I guess you may have read this too https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-reverse-effect-of-wpautop-and-wptexturize-on-multi-line-shortcode

Comment: Thank you again. I tried everything. Even from the link you have provided. Without any success whatsoever. I will keep looking into this. There has to be a way to solve this.

Comment: Wary of granny/eggs scenario but it could be time to take pliers to wpautop() There are exception regexes inside the function to deal with flukes like you are getting - maybe you could write one - example and link to the file // Under certain strange conditions it could create a P of entirely whitespace. $pee = preg_replace('|<p>\s*</p>|', '', $pee);    Something like find <div><p></a> replace using str_replace()<div></a> - you could put something silly so it stands out if you are in the ballpark. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L0

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I will try that. Thank you again.

Comment: I still wonder where the newline is coming from that makes the p  happen <div class="orange-button">Watch Video</div>HERE - newline
<p></a></div>

Comment: I still have no idea. Even though i am calling the function directly in php now i have to admit that i am still very bothered by it. I really wish there would be a way for me to figure this out. Would it help you if i would send you the files by email and maybe the link to the page or so?

Comment: I don't think I would see any more than you do - the code you have would not do it but it might get added by wpautop itself and then it finds the newline it has added and converts that - an order of execution thing - which might account for the quirks in autop itself. It probably adds a newline after a div to format the html but then finds it later. Only mention of div is in // Add a closing <p> inside <div>, <address>, or <form> tag if missing. 

554
        $pee = preg_replace('!<p>([^<]+)</(div|address|form)>!', "<p>$1</p></$2>", $pee); 
try comment it out?

Comment: Just tried it with no success again. I have absolutely no clue what is going on here at all.

Comment: I have just found out that it seems to be adding the <p> tag always in front of the </a> tag. So it might not even be connected to the divs at all.

Comment: Try commenting each regex one at a time and clear cache before testing. Might isolate it. Not sure what adds the newlines to format the html in the page.

Comment: Just tried something else. In the function shown above i have one link throughout the entire function and i keep getting the validation issue with it. But when i replace the one link with a new link for each element ( like picture and <p></p> ) i get a valid html result. So I think it must be connected to the a tag after all. If i can't solve this any other way then i will just go with the individual links for each element.

Comment: What happens if you separate it to the last line $string .= '</a></div> autop thinks this is malformatted html and is trying to correct it as it isn't finding the <a> at the start of the line - we will get punted into chat and I am not able to do chat at present. Would be interested to know which preg function in autop is doing it.

Comment: I will try that now. But i can tell you that it works perfectly if i comment out the line 499 ( $pee = preg_replace('!(<' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)!', "\n$1", $pee); ). It looks like this doesn't have any negative effect on the rest of the website.

Comment: The seperation of the last line of the $string doesn't do anything. But i am very happy with just commenting the line 499. That really seems to do the trick. Thank you so so much again for walking me through all of this and coming up with all of those ideas. Is there a way you can post this as an answer?

Comment: I wouldn't dare - it would get flamed  and I can't afford the rep! Feel free to post it as your fix and I will give it an upvote ;-) Magic, anyway. So glad you got it working. Won't be the last thing you will hear about wpautop I am sure. It usually elicits howls of disapproval when core files are edited - nd for good reason. Remember to update it when you update WordPress. Someone might know how to put it into your Child Theme to protect it but I don't have that answer.

Comment: I would be interested to know how to add a part to an existing function that would get executed at the same time as the original function - almost as it it were an include in the main function.

Comment: I just posted the answer we did come up with. Thank you very very much again Steve. Amazing to see how much effort you put into this!
As for your question, i honestly don't know how that could be done. I tried google but i did not find anything yet. But i will keep looking and i will let you know here when i have found something.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will automatically apply wpautop filter on your content, either directly added on post editor or generated by shortcode,

to avoid wordpress from adding undesired tags on your content,

you can wrap all the inline element with block element, without adding new line to that inline element, .e.g

`<div><a href="#">Hello</a></div>`

will output `<div><a href="#">Hello</a></div>`

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
</div>
```

will output `<div><p><a href="#">Hello</a><p></div>`

your options are;

1. trim all new line to the content generated by your shortcode, though this wouldn't be a good idea as having no newline on your HTML can affect CSS property

`return trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));`

2. Override wordpress default auto formatter with custom formatter,

this code below is builtin function on my theme

```
function my_custom_content_formatter($content) {
    $new_content = '';
    $pattern_full = '{(\[raw\].*?\[/raw\])}is';
    $pattern_contents = '{\[raw\](.*?)\[/raw\]}is';
    $pieces = preg_split($pattern_full, $content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
        if (preg_match($pattern_contents, $piece, $matches)) {
            $new_content .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $new_content .= wptexturize(wpautop($piece));
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}

// Remove the 2 main auto-formatters
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');

// apply new auto-formatter
add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_content_formatter', 99);
add_filter('widget_text', 'my_custom_content_formatter', 99);
```

You can then add your shortcode like this `[raw][video_startpage][/raw]`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried both options but neither of them work. I am sorry you went through so much trouble to help me figure this out.

Comment: not quite sure why the second function would not work, can you try commenting ```add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_content_formatter', 99);``` and ```add_filter('the_content', 'my_custom_content_formatter', 99);``` then see if wordpress ```wpautop``` & ```wptexturize``` would still work?

Comment: Tried that as well without success. I really don't know why i can't get this to work. It drives me insane.

Comment: The thing that i don't unterstand most of all is the fact that wordpress is only adding the opening p tag in the middle of the return of the function. The is no end tag at all. The whole thing would not really bother me that much ( although i have to admit that it is becoming kind of personal now ) if i could still get a valid html out of it. But when i check the validator it gives me a nesting rule violation.

Comment: try removing all your content from that page and only show the content of the shortcode, check view-source page and examine the outputted element, I also wonder why there's no closing tag on the output, can you post the whole output of your shortcode as well? starting from ```.featured-start``` class to its closing tag, you might better modify your actual shortcode.

Comment: This is the output of the entire function. I have other pages on that website with pretty much the same shortcode. On those pages there is only the shortcode as content of the page and i am having the same problem. I have played around with adding extra p tags to the function or removing all of them but nothing works.

Comment: hmm, can you just edit your question and put your whole function for the shortcode, I'll try to modify it,  also, you don't need to use clearing div, you can just set ```overflow:hidden``` and ```clear:both```

Comment: also, just to make sure there's no problem on your site, try enabled debug mode and install Query monitor and make sure there's no error or warning.

Comment: I edited my post. Also i installed the monitor and it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: I have found a "solution". I tried out different suggested thing but without success. The i simply called the functions without the shortcode inside of my template. I know that it is not really a solution to the actual problem but it helps me at least to get a valid html code. Thank you guys again for all the efford you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and since nothing above really worked, I have decided to solve it. So here is my solution (though only works for shortcodes that have the closing tags).

Just so we're all on the same page,having a basic shortcode for **row** and **col** that outputs divs with their speciffic classes, if we have this in wp editor:

```
lorem test
[row]
[col]inside col[/col]
[/row]
dolor
```

the result output will be :

```
<p>lorem test<br />
<div class="row "><div class="columns ">inside col</div></div><br />
dolor</p>
```

which is wrong, the correct way should be:

```
<p>lorem test</p>
<div class="row "><div class="columns ">inside col</div></div>
<p>dolor</p>
```

To achieve this we first replace the **wpautop** filter with our own

```
add_action('init','cod_custom_wpautop',90);
function cod_custom_wpautop() {
   remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
   remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');
   add_filter('the_content', 'cod_wpautop');
   add_filter('acf_the_content', 'cod_wpautop');
}
```

and then the actual function is mostly the same as the one on **wp-includes/formating.php** , but with our own changes:

```
function cod_wpautop( $pee, $br = true ) {
$pre_tags = array();

if ( trim($pee) === '' )
    return '';

// Just to make things a little easier, pad the end.
$pee = $pee . "\n";

/*
 * Pre tags shouldn't be touched by autop.
 * Replace pre tags with placeholders and bring them back after autop.
 */
if ( strpos($pee, '<pre') !== false ) {
    $pee_parts = explode( '</pre>', $pee );
    $last_pee = array_pop($pee_parts);
    $pee = '';
    $i = 0;

    foreach ( $pee_parts as $pee_part ) {
        $start = strpos($pee_part, '<pre');

        // Malformed html?
        if ( $start === false ) {
            $pee .= $pee_part;
            continue;
        }

        $name = "<pre wp-pre-tag-$i></pre>";
        $pre_tags[$name] = substr( $pee_part, $start ) . '</pre>';

        $pee .= substr( $pee_part, 0, $start ) . $name;
        $i++;
    }

    $pee .= $last_pee;
}
// Change multiple <br>s into two line breaks, which will turn into paragraphs.
$pee = preg_replace('|<br\s*/?>\s*<br\s*/?>|', "\n\n", $pee);

$allblocks = '(?:table|thead|tfoot|caption|col|colgroup|tbody|tr|td|th|div|dl|dd|dt|ul|ol|li|pre|form|map|area|blockquote|address|math|style|p|h[1-6]|hr|fieldset|legend|section|article|aside|hgroup|header|footer|nav|figure|figcaption|details|menu|summary)';

// Add a double line break above block-level opening tags.
$pee = preg_replace('!(<' . $allblocks . '[\s/>])!', "\n\n$1", $pee);

// Add a double line break below block-level closing tags.
$pee = preg_replace('!(</' . $allblocks . '>)!', "$1\n\n", $pee);

$shortcode_blocks = '(?:row|col)';
$pee = preg_replace('!(\[' . $shortcode_blocks . '[\s/\]])!', "\n\n$1", $pee);
$pee = preg_replace('!(\[/' . $shortcode_blocks . '\])!', "$1\n\n", $pee);

// Standardize newline characters to "\n".
$pee = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $pee);

// Find newlines in all elements and add placeholders.
$pee = wp_replace_in_html_tags( $pee, array( "\n" => " <!-- wpnl --> " ) );

// Collapse line breaks before and after <option> elements so they don't get autop'd.
if ( strpos( $pee, '<option' ) !== false ) {
    $pee = preg_replace( '|\s*<option|', '<option', $pee );
    $pee = preg_replace( '|</option>\s*|', '</option>', $pee );
}

/*
 * Collapse line breaks inside <object> elements, before <param> and <embed> elements
 * so they don't get autop'd.
 */
if ( strpos( $pee, '</object>' ) !== false ) {
    $pee = preg_replace( '|(<object[^>]*>)\s*|', '$1', $pee );
    $pee = preg_replace( '|\s*</object>|', '</object>', $pee );
    $pee = preg_replace( '%\s*(</?(?:param|embed)[^>]*>)\s*%', '$1', $pee );
}

/*
 * Collapse line breaks inside <audio> and <video> elements,
 * before and after <source> and <track> elements.
 */
if ( strpos( $pee, '<source' ) !== false || strpos( $pee, '<track' ) !== false ) {
    $pee = preg_replace( '%([<\[](?:audio|video)[^>\]]*[>\]])\s*%', '$1', $pee );
    $pee = preg_replace( '%\s*([<\[]/(?:audio|video)[>\]])%', '$1', $pee );
    $pee = preg_replace( '%\s*(<(?:source|track)[^>]*>)\s*%', '$1', $pee );
}

// Remove more than two contiguous line breaks.
$pee = preg_replace("/\n\n+/", "\n\n", $pee);

// Split up the contents into an array of strings, separated by double line breaks.
$pees = preg_split('/\n\s*\n/', $pee, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

// Reset $pee prior to rebuilding.
$pee = '';

// Rebuild the content as a string, wrapping every bit with a <p>.
foreach ( $pees as $tinkle ) {
    $pee .= '<p>' . trim($tinkle, "\n") . "</p>\n";
}

// Under certain strange conditions it could create a P of entirely whitespace.
$pee = preg_replace('|<p>\s*</p>|', '', $pee);

// Add a closing <p> inside <div>, <address>, or <form> tag if missing.
$pee = preg_replace('!<p>([^<]+)</(div|address|form)>!', "<p>$1</p></$2>", $pee);

// If an opening or closing block element tag is wrapped in a <p>, unwrap it.
$pee = preg_replace('!<p>\s*(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*</p>!', "$1", $pee);
$pee = preg_replace('!<p>\s*(\[/?' . $shortcode_blocks . '[^\]]*\])\s*</p>!', "$1", $pee);

// In some cases <li> may get wrapped in <p>, fix them.
$pee = preg_replace("|<p>(<li.+?)</p>|", "$1", $pee);

// If a <blockquote> is wrapped with a <p>, move it inside the <blockquote>.
$pee = preg_replace('|<p><blockquote([^>]*)>|i', "<blockquote$1><p>", $pee);
$pee = str_replace('</blockquote></p>', '</p></blockquote>', $pee);

// If an opening or closing block element tag is preceded by an opening <p> tag, remove it.
$pee = preg_replace('!<p>\s*(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)!', "$1", $pee);
$pee = preg_replace('!<p>\s*(\[/?' . $allblocks . '[^\]]*\])!', "$1", $pee);

// If an opening or closing block element tag is followed by a closing <p> tag, remove it.
$pee = preg_replace('!(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*</p>!', "$1", $pee);
$pee = preg_replace('!(\[/?' . $allblocks . '[^\]]*\])\s*</p>!', "$1", $pee);

// Optionally insert line breaks.
if ( $br ) {
    // Replace newlines that shouldn't be touched with a placeholder.
    $pee = preg_replace_callback('/<(script|style).*?<\/\\1>/s', '_autop_newline_preservation_helper', $pee);

    // Normalize <br>
    $pee = str_replace( array( '<br>', '<br/>' ), '<br />', $pee );

    // Replace any new line characters that aren't preceded by a <br /> with a <br />.
    $pee = preg_replace('|(?<!<br />)\s*\n|', "<br />\n", $pee);

    // Replace newline placeholders with newlines.
    $pee = str_replace('<WPPreserveNewline />', "\n", $pee);
}

// If a <br /> tag is after an opening or closing block tag, remove it.
$pee = preg_replace('!(</?' . $allblocks . '[^>]*>)\s*<br />!', "$1", $pee);
$pee = preg_replace('!(\[/?' . $shortcode_blocks . '[^\]]*\])\s*<br />!', "$1", $pee);

// If a <br /> tag is before a subset of opening or closing block tags, remove it.
$pee = preg_replace('!<br />(\s*</?(?:p|li|div|dl|dd|dt|th|pre|td|ul|ol)[^>]*>)!', '$1', $pee);
$pee = preg_replace( "|\n</p>$|", '</p>', $pee );

// Replace placeholder <pre> tags with their original content.
if ( !empty($pre_tags) )
    $pee = str_replace(array_keys($pre_tags), array_values($pre_tags), $pee);

// Restore newlines in all elements.
if ( false !== strpos( $pee, '<!-- wpnl -->' ) ) {
    $pee = str_replace( array( ' <!-- wpnl --> ', '<!-- wpnl -->' ), "\n", $pee );
}

return $pee;
}
```

To explain it a bit, we've added a **$shortcode_blocks** that does the same thing as **$allblocks** does , essentially making them recognize as a block and not just a simple text. This way first those tags will be wrapped with a paragraph tag that will be later removed.

Works for me, so hope it will for you to ;)