# wordpress widget addng extra p tags

Tags: wordpress

I have a short code like this:

```
function requestaquote($atts, $content = null){
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'text'=>'',
        'link'=>'',
        'colour'=>''
        ), $atts));     
    return '<div class="speed-button"><img src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/request-a-quote.jpg" alt="request a quote " /><p class="requstaquote">'.esc_attr($text).'</p></div><!--speed-button-->';
}
add_shortcode( 'quotetext', 'requestaquote' );
```

It's working except that its introducing extra `<p></p>` pairs like this:

```
<div class="textwidget">
<p></p>
<div class="speed-button">...</div>
<p></p>
</div>
```

which is messing up my formatting.

I have tried `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`

How do I removed these `<p></p>` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can pospone the `wp_autop` because it processes before the shortcode output:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Or use the [`cleanup_shortcode_fix()`](http://pastebin.com/USBetJAj) function:

```
function cleanup_shortcode_fix($content) {
    $array = array('<p>[' => '[', ']</p>' => ']', ']<br />' => ']', ']<br>' => ']');
    $content = strtr($content, $array);
    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix');
$string = preg_replace('/<p>s*</p>/', '', $string);
add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix', 1);
```

Source : [Remove auto added <p> from a page that has no literal content (uses shortcodes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177274/remove-auto-added-p-from-a-page-that-has-no-literal-content-uses-shortcodes)

Comment: you can use plugin as well : https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-empty-paragraph-fix/

Comment: I thought your clean_up_shortcode_fix function looked promising. I copied into funtions.php and got the error:  Call to undefined function preg_replace_()  any ideas please?

Comment: thanks - I now get ... preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'p'

Comment: ok don't use `cleanup_shortcode_fix` function. just add `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);` in your functions.php file and check.

Comment: thanks for you time Milap - but that didn't work either when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the new lines as it appears that the new lines are whats being made into paragraphs.

```
return str_replace("\r\n", '', $content);
```

Comment: sorry - didn't work - i think its because its added before and after the actual shortcode

Comment: last and easy thing is to make the p tags display none. Not a perfect solution but it will help though