# can't use first-child css to set display

Tags: html, css

I am using wordpress and its generating this code:

```
<aside class="left-hand-column">
 <div class="textwidget">
  <p></p> ...1
   <div class="pdf-download">
    <p> ... 2
     <a href="http://www.kusuma.ee-web.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/strategy2015-2018.pdf" target="_blank">download pdf</a>
    </p>
   </div>
  <p></p> ...3
 </div>
</aside>
```

I want to remove the effects of the `<p></p>` tag pairs.

I thought I could set display:none for them like this:

```
.textwidget p:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

but its making 1 and 2 p's disappear and leaving 3 - how could I get it to do what I need please?

Comment: Because `3` isn't the `first-child`? It's already the second child based on your HTML structure.

Comment: Instead of sweeping it under the rug, consider *fixing* your bad input that are causing this problem to begin with.

Comment: well Mr zzzz I had a previous question months ago about doing exactly that. Yes, its a fiddle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743042/wordpress-widget-addng-extra-p-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with jquery you can use this

```
$('.textwidget p').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().length === 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the `p` which are direct descendants of `.textwidget`:

```
.textwidget > p {
    display:none;
}
```

You can remove `:empty` paragraph tags instead:

```
.textwidget p:empty {
    display:none;
}
```