# WP removing all br tags from my pages when I try to edit them

Tags: html, wordpress

WordPress 3.7.1, one of the pages contains a lot of code looking like this:

```
...
<td>
    <strong>Text</strong><br/>
    Text<br/>
    Text
</td>
```

I know, not the best HTML, however, changes of the HTML structure are not possible due to various reasons. I can save the page and it works fine, however, when I try to edit the page again (no TinyMCE or similar installed) WP stripped all the br tags without even asking (no, I've not even switched to the visual editor, HTML edit only).

I've searched the WWW, but couldn't find a working solution yet. Most fixes are TinyMCE-related.

Also the very high voted [Removing <p> and <br/> tags in WordPress posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts) didn't change a thing.

Anyone knows a solution or on which part of WP I have to look to find the problem? I'm unfortunately far away from being a WP expert.

Edit: Installing the Text Control plugin and setting everything to "No Formatting" didn't help either,.

Comment: Can you install TinyMCE? Seems like that may be one option that will allow editing + formatting the way you want (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/editor-removing-br-and-p-tags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we destroyed it by using the Visual Editor in a previous version of the document which generated some invalid HTML which in turn confused the HTML editor thus removing all br tags completely.

After making the HTML valid again it does not strip the br tags anymore, still, weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the 'visual' tab from the editor via your user profile. That would stop it defaulting to 'visual' and overwriting the changes made on the text tab during those subsequent edits, and the text tab accepts html just fine!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was also very frustrated trying to find a solution to this problem.
Realised that the solution was a simple one.

The editor.js and editor.js.min files have preg_match and replace functions to replace `<p> tags with "".`

```
Separate <div> containing <p>
//content = content.replace( /<div( [^>]*)?>\s*<p>/gi, '<div$1>\n\n' );
```

comment the above line
Similarly

```
// Remove <p> and <br />
//content = content.replace( /\s*<p>/gi, '' );
//content = content.replace( /\s*<\/p>\s*/gi, '\n\n' );
```

The explaination given in the documentation is that it is for Prettying up the source editor, so doesnt look harmful to remove it.
Thanks