# word-break: keep-all; not working? (with wordpress)

Tags: css

So , as an Embedded C developer, trying to help a friend out with CSS (which I had known a long-long time ago) is proving a pain.

My problem is that (using wordpress and having no access to the hosting account) I cannot seem to be able to stop words from breaking at the end of the line. I have tried everything I know of / have seen on the web, from whitespace to word-break: keep-all;, nothing seems to work.
Has anyone had the same issue, I can only seem to be able to find answers for the exact opposite (people needing words to be broken);

the domain is http://diette.ro

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.blog-post p strong em{
     word-break: normal;
}`

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the content is *full* of `&nbsp;`s instead of spaces. An `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space which prevents words to be split/broken. The HTML output for one of the paragraphs now looks like this:

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Așadar, la noi&nbsp;în&nbsp;salon te vom&nbsp;întâmpină&nbsp;cu un ambient &nbsp;cald&nbsp;și&nbsp;prietenos, îți&nbsp;&nbsp;vom&nbsp;asculta&nbsp;nevoile&nbsp;și dorințele tale. &nbsp;Totodată, &nbsp;cu ajutorul analizei corporale vom afla&nbsp;și&nbsp;nevoile organismului iar&nbsp;împreună&nbsp;vom&nbsp;plănui&nbsp;o „călătorie”&nbsp;în&nbsp;care &nbsp;vei&nbsp;învață cu&nbsp;siguranță,&nbsp;&nbsp;noțiuni&nbsp;simple dar utile pentru a te&nbsp;împrietenii&nbsp;cu propriul&nbsp;organism&nbsp;! În tot&nbsp;acest&nbsp;timp&nbsp;noi&nbsp;te vom&nbsp;susține&nbsp;oferindu-ți&nbsp;informațiile&nbsp;necesare, ca totul să devină realizabil&nbsp;și&nbsp;ușor&nbsp;de&nbsp;țintit! Paleta de servicii aflate la noi, cele de &nbsp;recomandări și programe nutriționale,&nbsp;proceduri de&nbsp;remodelare corporală dar&nbsp;și&nbsp;masaje de relaxare&nbsp;și&nbsp;terapii energetice, ne vor ajuta să&nbsp;obținem&nbsp;rezultatele&nbsp;dorite.
```

It is no surprise that the text is not broken, because your HTML tells the browser not to break.

You should remove the CSS that you tried to add (the word-break ones) and simply get rid of those tags. The cause of this might be how your friend put the text in Wordpress. If he copied the text from a word processor, non-breaking spaces may have been added automatically, or something else happened. So what you do is, open the content in HTML form in Wordpress, do a find-and-replace of `&nbsp;` with  (a single space), and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not CSS the problem is that wordpress injects `<p>` and `<br>` tags in content.  Ask your friend to install a *noautop* plugin, e.g., https://wordpress.org/plugins/toggle-wpautop/, or do what this answer says:

[Removing <p> and <br/> tags in WordPress posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts)

Answer (score 0):

You have the following `!important`s in `style.css` which override your `keep-all`:

```
pre, p {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
  word-break: break-all !important;
}
```

You can either try using `!important` once more on your `keep-all` and make sure it reads it last:

```
p {
  word-break: keep-all !important;
}
```

Or remove those `!important` from `style.css` and give a deeper `p` impact without `!important`: (using a `class` or `id`)

```
p.class {
  word-break: keep-all;
}
```