# Wordpress changed a code introduced in the page editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I copied the code below into the editor

```
<div class="services_container clearfix">
<a href="it" class="service service-it">
<div class="service_ttl">
IT support
</div>
<span>More</span>
</a>
<a href="legal" class="service service-legal">
<div class="service_ttl">
Legal support
</div>
<span>More</span>
</a>
```

But if I look in firebug, the code output looks like this

```
<div class="services_container clearfix">
<a class="service service-it" href="it/index.php">
<p></p>
<div class="service_ttl">IT support</div>
</a>
<p>
<a class="service service-it" href="it/index.php">
<span>More</span>
<br>
</a>
<br>
<a class="service service-legal" href="legal/index.php"></a>
</p>
<a class="service service-legal" href="legal/index.php">
<div class="service_ttl">Legal support</div>
</a>
<p>
<a class="service service-legal" href="legal/index.php">
<span>More</span>
```

That is tags  is repeated two or three times and this breaks the page design.

Obviously I need in the writing settings disable option "WordPress should correct invalidly nested XHTML automatically".
But I don't have this option in the writing settings.
I have found and commented out all calls of `force_balance_tags` function.
Then I have deleted and recreated page, but it not helped.

I use Worpress 4.7.

Comment: Did You Check This Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts

Comment: Thank you. Removing the filter `wpautop` helped.