# Wordpress and Bootstrap for "<p>"

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to create a bootstrap based WordPress. But the out put doesn't give me the same. Attached screenshot.[image]

[image]

The code for wordpress is below:

```
    <div class="container">


      <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/security-and-surveillance-banner.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style="width:100%;display:block">



      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

 <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="row">
          <?php query_posts('showposts=3');?>
            <?php if(have_posts()) :?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

              </div>  
            <?php endwhile;?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
</div> 

  </div>
```

and the cited code is below, check the code, and seems to be the same for HTML, not sure why giving me different view?

```
<div class="container">


  <img src="images/sample1.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" style="width:100%;display:block">
  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to output is that same paragraph font style and background color. If I remove jumbotron, then it would be the same as I wish, but background color will be removed, which is not my expected.

Comment: You have an `<a>` tag wrapped around the title, and `the_content()` will wrap in `<p>` tags.

Comment: @RyanHipkiss Thank you for reply, I tried on the cited code to add <a> on the <h2> and the output doesn't make big difference, just changed to blue hyper link. But on wordpress, the output paragraph font size becomes bigger than cited one, do you know why? thanks.

Comment: fixed by post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts