# <br> is appearing after <span> element on the front end, but it is not in the back end. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: html, wordpress

I am using the Enfold theme from Kriesi, the Avia layout builder, the 'tab' setup in the Avia layout builder, the plugin 'Ultimate FAQ', and shortcodes from that plugin to pull through different categories of FAQs.

In my first tab, I have this code:

```
<span class="ewd-ufaq-expand-all"><span class="ewd-ufaq-toggle-all-symbol">c</span> Expand All</span>
<span class="ewd-ufaq-collapse-all ewd-ufaq-hidden"><span class="ewd-ufaq-toggle-all-symbol">C</span> Collapse All</span>
[select-faq faq_id='6486']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='a-to-c']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='d-to-h']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='i-to-n']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='o-to-v']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='w-to-z']
```

The `<span>` stuff is code from the FAQ creator to expand/collapse all FAQ answers. [Here is my page](http://staging.nwcm.com/2017/07/01/faq-custom-css-2/#tab-id-1), if you use the page inspector it shows two `<br>`s between the expand/collapse control and the FAQ.

But I didn't put any `<br>` there.  I don't know where they're coming from.

Comment: I know nothing about how that layout builder works. Is it turning newline characters into `<br>` elements?

Comment: no, it is not.  I can see the 'text' editor (where code shows) and there are no <br> elements

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about. You provide raw text, and then the system interprets that text when it renders it to the page I imagine, which is why `[ultimate-faqs...]` gets turned into markup. It looks like each newline character in your text is replaced by a `<br> `element, because I'm seeing `<br>` elements between each of your category widgets.

Comment: Is this possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6625458/497418?

Comment: None of the information on that link made sense to me.  HTML and CSS I can do, php is lost on me.  I tried removing all the spaces so I just had a string of code with no spaces.  It made no changes to the front end view.

Comment: I hate to be dismissive but ["Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers."](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). If you're unable or unwilling to attempt to solve your own problem you might want to consider hiring a programmer who has the skills needed to fix the problem. Otherwise, how can you expect to even know when a proposed answer would answer your question?

Comment: I am neither unable or unwilling, I just need a little more context so I know what to google to teach myself how to implement the solutions provided.  I'm also on a budget of $0 and tasked by my employer with fixing this.  If I could hire a programmer I would have already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this is a Wordpress question.

By default Wordpress injects `<br>` tags into the content where a new line occurs. It's designed to help content writers. You won't see it in the text editor as it's added behind the scenes via a 'filter'.

Unfortunately the only way you're going to overcome your problem is to write PHP or JS code in the theme file itself. HTML and CSS will not work here. There's a question that deals with this problem using filters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts).

**EDIT:** Something you could try is removing any whitespace between elements to stop the 
 tags being injected i.e;

```
<span class="ewd-ufaq-expand-all"><span class="ewd-ufaq-toggle-all-symbol">c</span> Expand All</span><span class="ewd-ufaq-collapse-all ewd-ufaq-hidden"><span class="ewd-ufaq-toggle-all-symbol">C</span> Collapse All</span>[select-faq faq_id='6486']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='a-to-c']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='d-to-h']
[ultimate-faqs-include_category='i-to-n']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='o-to-v']
[ultimate-faqs include_category='w-to-z']
```

This will largely depend on how the editor works though so no promises.

Answer (score -1):

This works via console.  Try placing it in a script tag prior to the end of the body element.

```
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('span.ewd-ufaq-collapse-all').next('br').remove();
    });
```

Comment: I don't know what a script tag means and I don't know how to find the end of the body of a WordPress post.  I'm sorry