# Remove br and p tags from textarea in WordPress post

Tags: wordpress, textarea

I write in a post of WordPress code snippets in C. To highlight those code snippets with the Ace editor, I have to put each one of them within textarea.

The problem is that the textarea causes br and p tags to appear in it.

[image: Ace editor with a program written in C]

I read this:
[Removing <p> and <br/> tags in WordPress posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625458/removing-p-and-br-tags-in-wordpress-posts)

I added **remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop');** function in **functions.php** file. This has indeed removed from all the textarea the br and p tags, but also removed all the break lines and separation between paragraphs in all the posts.

Is there a way to use the **remove_filter** function only on all textarea tags?

If I create an HTML page with textarea the tags br and p do not appear. The problem only occurs in WordPress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html

**Update:**

This plug-in has resolved the problem:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html

Thanks to those who tried to help! :-)

Comment: Does it work if you use `<pre></pre>` instead of `<textarea>`? [`<pre>` is intended to show preformatted text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) (e.g. code snippets).

Comment: If I use the **pre** then part of the syntax of C deleted, like **<stdio.h>**

Comment: may be best way is to use shortcode to add your code snippets and filter content within posts